# Why am I not getting a functioning JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, jscrollpane

I have a JFrame window, and I'd like to add a scrollable JTable towards the middle of it. I have a method, called `collectionTableScrollPane()` that generates the `JScrollPane` (and I know this is guaranteed to work).

I then proceed to add it to my `mainPanel` panel. However, I'd like there to be some forced 30px padding on the left and right of the `JScrollPane`. Logically, I would create a holding `JPanel` with a centred `FlowLayout`, and add `Box.createHorizontalStrut(30)` either side of the `JScrollPane`.

```
JPanel tableHolderPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
mainPanel.add(tableHolderPanel);
tableHolderPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));
tableHolderPanel.add(collectionTableScrollPane());
tableHolderPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));
```

However, I'm getting a strange result, where the JScrollPane in the middle of the window (denoted by the arrows) sort of becomes ineffectual.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

[image: 1]

Note that the `JTable` contains four rows, of which only two are visible.

Comment: Do you want the table to grow and occupy remaining space? This will not happen in flow layout. The table is at its preferred size.

Comment: @IngoKegel the table is not at its correct size as there are four rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some issues in the past when i used a `JScrollPane` inside a panel with a `FlowLayout`. The behaviour could be tricky, when the content grow, the horizontal scrollbar may appear or the FlowLayout should add a new line.

In your case, i will replace the `FlowLayout` by a `BorderLayout` :

```
JPanel tableHolderPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(tableHolderPanel);
tableHolderPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30), BorderLayout.WEST);
tableHolderPanel.add(collectionTableScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
tableHolderPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, `Box` is suppose to be used with the `BoxLayout`, this may be causing you some issues. Instead, why not use a [EmptyBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html) on the `tableHolderPane`

Comment: +1. I had completely forgotten about the EmptyBorder technique using the  always-useful `BorderFactory`. I ended up using it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`BoxLayout` accepting size that came from `JComponents`, the same issue with default `FlowLayout` pre_implemented for `JPanel`

1. you have to returns `PreferredSize` by overrode `JPanel` nested `JScrollPane`,
2. use another `LayoutManager`, e.g. `GridBagLayout` or todays `MigLayout`
3. use `NestedLayout`, by using `BorderLayout` where you put two `JLabel`s (e.i. that returns `PreferredSize`) to the `EAST` and `WEST` area
4. everything depends if you really to want to create the empty area and if shoud be resiziable or not